# Passing Values from Javascript to PHP via XMLHttpRequests

Tags: php, post, xmlhttprequest

I am attempting to send some data collected from user input from a javascript form to a php file for processing.  I can accomplish the feat when hardcoding php values and just sending with no arguments, like this...

```
xhr.open("post", "http://host/path/script.php", true);
xhr.send();
```

but as soon as I attempt to send the array with user input values like this...

```
xhr.open("post", "http://host/path/script.php", true);
xhr.send(data);
```

I get an "undefined error" not too sure why.  The variable is of type "FormData" and I don't really think the issue has anything to do with the variable itself, just not sure why it works with no arguments but not with the data argument.

To rule out same origin policy issues I have these headers in my php file...

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description, X-Request-With');
```

I am fairly new to this though, so I may have something wrong here.

EDIT: The console does infact give me this error...

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://host/path/script.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://javascripthost/path' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So it appears there is an access control issue...but I don't know how to fix it

EDIT 2: Adding headers in case this information helps...

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Request URL:http://host/path/script.php
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost
Origin:http://host2
Referer:http://host2/script
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36
Response Headers
Allow:OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Content-Length:0
Date:Thu, 02 Oct 2014 14:08:24 GMT
Public:OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Comment: How are you constructing `data`? Exactly what error message do you get? From which line? Look in the Net tab of your developer tools. Do you see the request you expect? Is it formatted the way you expect? Is it a POST request? What about the response?

Comment: Look at the request you are making. I'd speculate that you are triggering a preflight OPTIONS request and not handling it on the server.

Comment: I think you might be correct about the OPTIONS request...in the Network tab the method says OPTIONS not POST...but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong?  I specify post...I don't know what a preflight OPTIONS request is

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Comment: thanks for the link...I'm still a bit confused about how to handle the preflighted OPTIONS request.  When I look in the network tab I only see 'content-type' as the request-header

Comment: I can see `Origin:http://localhost:41434` in the request headers in the material you quoted.

Comment: yes for testing purposed right now I am using 2 local IIS sites, that one is where the javascript resides the other is where the PHP resides.  I am doing this because once in production the PHP scripts will be on a dedicated server because the processing I am doing is will be quite taxing.  But I guess its better to hide any actual info like I've done elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed my problem was adding an Access-Control-Allow-Origins header to my actual site with the PHP script in IIS.  I thought I could do it in the PHP file but apparently not.  Hope this helps anyone with a similar issue.

As a side note, you can often avoid having to deal with preflight OPTION requests if you don't use a progress bar.  For some reason it seems all (or all I've test with) browsers handle requests with a progress bar as preflight OPTION requests.

Answer (score -2):

It is most likely you are not using the right attributes. When trying to send a POST data, usually make sure if your spelling is right.

```
    var data = "username="+username+"&country="+country;
    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'inc/ajaxPostHandler.php', true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(data);
```

Comment: my FormData variable appears to have the desired values stored in it correctly

Comment: @mgrenier are you trying to post into another domain?

Comment: @Contax — See the question and the comments on the question.

Comment: @mgrenier [it is not possible to send requests to other domains](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/same-origin-policy/info) <-- read!! There is another way for doing this.

Comment: it IS possible, you just have to allow those domains.  hence this header in my php file..."header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');" if you read your own link there is a link on the page abour circumventing the same origin policy

Comment: I've just edited that tag wiki page to make the availability of bypass mechanisms clearer.